# how to toggle dynamic div dropdown NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building an ecommerce store using NEXT.JS and REDUX. In product listing page, I have filter section having Size, Color etc. On click the heading the content should be toggled. I have tried using the below code, but it is not working as expected.

```
const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(0);

function toggle(index) {
    setShowMe(index);
}

<div className="other">
    <h6>Refine</h6>
    <hr/>
    {products.filter.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div className="single">
                <div className="title" onClick={() => toggle(index)}>
                    <p className="float-left">{item.title}</p>
                    <p className="float-right"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={showMe === index ? faChevronUp : faChevronDown}/></p>
                </div>
                <ul style={{display: showMe === index ? "block" : "none"}}>
                    {item.items.map((single, index1) => (
                        <li key={index1}>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"/> {single.items_value}</label>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Initially index 0 is open and others are closed. Onclick index 0 it is not closing. Onclick index 1 it opens and index 0 closes.

I want the output as, initially all the dropdown should be open. Upon clicking each div it should be closed and clicking on same it should be opened. How to alter my code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if clicked item is already open, you can get current value of a `setState` in first param of its `setter` function:

```
// use an empty array for intial value:
const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState([]);

// after you got `products`:
setShowMe(Array(products.filter.length).fill(0).map((_, index) => index))

function toggle(index) {
    setShowMe(currentShowMe => currentShowMe.includes(index)
      ? currentShowMe.filter(i => i !== index)
      : [...currentShowMe, index]);
}
...
<ul style={{display: showMe.includes(index) ? "block" : "none"}}>
...
```